# "Question viewed by" in moderator flag interface shows my avatar twice

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

Not a particularly troublesome bug, but someone might want to know about it.

I assume this is not the expected behavior:

[image: flag interface]

The HTML shows

```
question viewed by:<br /><br />

        <span title="ff524 - 1 hour ago">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/byCOn.png?s=24&amp;g=1" width="24" height="24" />
        </span> 


        <span title="ff524 - 1 hour ago">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/byCOn.png?s=24&amp;g=1" width="24" height="24" />
        </span>
```

Comment: mods can see who viewed a question!??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ No, this interface shows which *mods* have already viewed a question that has been flagged.

Comment: oh... that's less surprising :P

Comment: Alternate timelines confirmed.